# TabbedPage (BottomNavigationBar) as Navigation Page and child pages are also navigation pages but Navigation stack should be work together?

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigationbar, bottomnavigationview

I have a requirement as below,

```
Dashboard Page (MainPage)
---->  Home Page (which is NavigationPage and BottomNavigationBar Page)
--------> 4 Child Pages(for bottomnavigation bar - Home Page) all are Navigation Pages.
```

So here is the problem, If I enable the navigation bar for all child pages then two navigation bars are coming, one for HomePage (which is navigationpage) and second one is for child page.
If I hide the navigationbar for Childpage back navigation is not working as expected because this navigation bar related to HomePage not for childpages...

How can I solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This can be solved if you HomePage is not a NavigationPage.

Comment: @HobbyDev thanks for your reply, I required HomePage as Navigation Page and more over If remove Navigation Page for HomePage I need to make chidpages with navigation bar which is giving blinking issue for the very first time.For example, I have 4 child pages with navigation bar so If main page doesn't have navigation page then if try to navigate to the child pages for the very firsttime navigation bar removes and adds for a second...How can we solve this issue?

Comment: Can you provide code of the project for testing.